# Cloud Functions deployment failiure from Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I seem to be unable to deploy Google Cloud Functions successfully.

I have created a project on Google Cloud Platform and then proceeded to link it to Firebase via the Firebase console. I select ADD PROJECT and Add Firebase to an existing project. Everything seems to link.

When I try to deploy a cloud function (the simple helloWorld that comes with installing firebase-tools) I keep getting deployment errors. This also happens when trying to deploy functions from Google Cloud Functions dashboard as well.

The error is something aboud setting up the environment.
After ttrying to rename the function to something else, I seem to have luck with deploying but then the function but there is a communication error `Function load error: Error: cannot communicate with function.`

I am unable to deploy functions on two of my projects, and firebase has been acting very strangely in the last few days, so can somebody please tell me if I am doing something wrong or is it a Firebase glitch

Comment: If you have obvious and unexpected errors coming from Firebase products, you should contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because there is an outage starting from early this morning. Check status here: https://status.firebase.google.com